# Understanding the UIViewController lifecycle and passing of variables in iOS in Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uiviewcontroller

I was trying to understand what's going on in a UIViewController->UIView when loaded from Interface Builder or Storyboards.

I start wondering about how things works in background when facing the most commons of problem, which is passing parameters between controllers.

In a Storyboards using the navigation controller I have a table view loaded by CoreData element, and the single element is passed as NSManagedObjectID onto the next controller via @property in the segue method for displaying a detail view.
On the receiving controller I am doing a check of the existence and reconstruct the full object when needed.

At this point, comes the question, where's the best place to put and handle this logic ? 
I come from a Java EE background, where the controller is called a servlet, and a servlet for performance reason may be initialized once and shared by many users (by means of Thread Pool) and therefore is discouraged (dangerous is more appropriate) to have instance variable.
Just because a @property is an instance variable I don't want to fall in the same mechanism, my UIViewController is instantiated once and the CoreData object stays the same in case of view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, each view controller manages a single view and its subviews.  Even if you used a UISplitViewController to put two identical view controllers on the screen at once, they would be two separate instances of the view controller class, and I believe storyboards instantiate a new view controller for each segue performed (though I could be wrong).  Thus it's not only perfectly safe to use properties—it's expected practice.

Comment: In addition, do you think it's part of "best practices" to check for @property in viewDidLoad method ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "check for".  Do you mean "assert that the property has a valid value"?  If there's absolutely no circumstance under which the value should be invalid at that point, I don't see why not.  It's not commonly done, but programming defensively is usually wise.  It might be better to do that sort of check in `-viewWillAppear:`, though, which happens right before the view is displayed—something could force the view to load long before it has to be ready to go on the screen.